# Spring boot Constructor Autowired Exception

Tags: spring, constructor, spring-boot, autowired

I have this classes in my spring boot App(spring hibernate/data/jpa/web):

pkg entity:

```
public interface Base {
// getter/setter methods
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbsBase implements Base {
// common fields & getter/setter methods
}

@Entity(name = "Config")
@Table(name = "config")
public class Config extends AbsBase implements Base, Serializable {
  //additional fields & getter/setter methods
}
```

pkg repository:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T extends Base> extends JpaRepository<T, Integer> {}

@Repository
public interface ConfigRepository extends BaseRepository<Config> {
//Queries
}
```

pkg service:

```
@Transactional
public interface BaseService<T extends Base> {

    @Transactional  void add(T obj);
    @Transactional  void edit(T obj);
    //Etc..
}

public abstract class AbsBaseService<T extends Base> implements BaseService<T> {

    private BaseRepository<T> repository;

    public AbsBaseService(BaseRepository<T> repository) {
        super();
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override   public void add(T obj) { repository.save(obj); }
    @Override   public void edit(T obj) { repository.save(obj); }
    // Etc
}

@Service
public class ConfigService extends AbsBaseService<Config> implements BaseService<Config> {

    private ConfigRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public ConfigService(ConfigRepository repository) {
        super(repository);
        this.repository = repository;
    }
    // Etc.
}
```

If I don't create any Controller all work, but if I create a controller:

pkg controller:

```
public interface BaseController<T extends Base> { // methods }

public abstract class AbsBaseController<T extends Base> implements BaseController<T> {

    private BaseService<T> service;

    public AbsBaseController(BaseService<T> service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

@Override
@RequestMapping(value = "/Add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addAction(@ModelAttribute("entity") T entity, BindingResult result, Model model,
        final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    service.add(entity, result);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return addUrl;
    }
}

@Controller
public class ConfigController extends AbsBaseController<Config> implements BaseController<Config> {

    private ConfigService configService;

    @Autowired
    public ConfigController(ConfigService configService) {
        super(configService);
        this.configService = configService;
    }
}
```

I get this error (error autowired ConfigService in ConfigController):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configControllerImpl' defined in file [C:\workspace-sts\prueba_boot_thymeleaf\target\classes\prueba\controller\config\ConfigControllerImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [prueba.service.config.ConfigServiceImpl]: No qualifying bean of type [prueba.service.config.ConfigServiceImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [prueba.service.config.ConfigServiceImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at prueba.BootThymeleafApplication.main(BootThymeleafApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [prueba.service.config.ConfigServiceImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

The first question is:
I have annotated @Transaction the BaseService interface and its methods. It's correct? Better in AbsBaseService class?

I see that configService constructor executes before Exception. 
Why not Autowired?

---

### UPDATE

I need constructor @Autowired because I implement common methods in abstract/superclass generic service/controller.

The inheritance tree:
AbsBaseXXXX  -->   AbsBaseCodeNameXXXX  -->   AbsBaseCodeNamePeriodXXXX

Config extends from AbsBase and implements Base.
    ConfigService extends from AbsBaseService<> and implements BaseService<> (use ConfigRepository)
    ConfigController extends from AbsBaseController<> and implements BaseController<> (use ConfigService)

I have a generic abstract classes for common method implementation:
Interfaces for entity:
    Base, BaseCodeName, BaseCodeNamePeriod....

- Abstract generic entity class: 
  AbsBase, AbsBaseCodeName, AbsBaseCodeNamePeriod....
- Generic Interfaces:
  BaseRepository, BaseCodeNameRepository, BaseCodeNamePeriodRepository,...
- Abstract generic service (That they need corresponding generic repository):
  AbsBaseService, AbsBaseCodeNameService,AbsBaseCodeNamePeriodService,...
- Abstract generic controller (that they need corresponding generic service):
  AbsBaseController, etc...

Comment: Where is you class that launches Spring boot (the package), and where are your controllers and services ? Maybe the Service bean is not being scanned at all

Comment: The code:     https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4DUWMYsjWtdVVRibDFZOVhac2s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

Create Service interface:
IConfigService extends BaseService

Change Service class:
ConfigService extends AbsBaseService implements IConfigService

In ControllerConfig replace ConfigService for IConfigService

If I use interface work but if i use class don't work. I don't understand why but it works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, most of you code could be simplified, at least to test that it works well:

```
@Transactional
public interface BaseService<T extends Base> {

    void add(T obj); // No need to repeat @Transactional here, unless you want to override default behaviour (says, read_only, for instance)
    void edit(T obj);
    //Etc..
}

// Not much use of an Abstract class here, all methods are exposed in the interface already

@Service
public class ConfigService implements BaseService<Config> {

    // Autowire the field directly. Constructor not needed anymore in this case
    @Autowired
    private ConfigRepository repository;
    // Etc.
}
```

The controller will follow the same guideline as the service.

This should work alright now. If not, you need to update your question with the full stack trace (or at least the last `caused by` block, which is the one really meaningful).

Comment: In abstract class (Service and Controller) I implement the common methods from another Service/Controller classes like Config.

Comment: Ok, this doesn't change much the solution, just adds clarity (shorter code :)). The point here is to put the `@Autowired` annotation on the property itself

Comment: Did you test it anyway ? That could help troubleshot the problem

Comment: Now if i don't have controllers it works, but if I use property @Autowired doesn't work (I spend more time).

Comment: Could you zip your application, and post the link to it ? The code you posted seems alright, so the clue may be somewhere else

Comment: I make another test.

Comment: Any idea @alexandre-fillatre ?

Comment: Since you accepted your own answer, I didn't continue investigating. I'll take a look now

Answer (score 0):

According to the code posted at https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4DUWMYsjWtdVVRibDFZOVhac2s, it is now clear for me what you're trying to achieve.

You want to create a hierarchy of classes (services, for instance), that define some functionalities at each level. For instance:

- `RepoA` defines a `methodA` method.
- `RepoB` extends `RepoA` and
  defines a `methodB` method.
- `ServiceA` uses the `RepoA` class to
  expose this method
- `ServiceB` extends `ServiceA` and expose its
  methods and `ServiceA` methods
- And so forth...

Debugging your application, I found out that Spring tries to create a new `AccountService` bean rather than using the existing one when this code is called:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Account")
public class AccountController extends AbsBaseDataController<Account> {

    private AccountService service;

    @Autowired
    public AccountController(AccountService service) {
        super(service);
        this.service = service;
        System.out.println("AccountController-CONSTRUCTOR");
    }
}
```

This is because you're using the `AccountService` class directly, **rather than an interface**. This is what matters here, because Spring creates a proxy around your classes to be able to use AOP on them. So when it comes to autowire it, classes mismatch (you think an instance of your class is injected, but this is actually a `com.sun.proxy.Proxy`).

Since those Java proxies implement your classes' interfaces, you should create an interface for your `AccountService` (say `IAccountService`), and use it instead of the raw `AccountService` class in your `AccountController` class' constructor:

The interface

```
public interface IAccountService extends BaseDataService<Account> {
}
```

The controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Account")
public class AccountController extends AbsBaseDataController<Account> {

    private IAccountService service;

    @Autowired
    public AccountController(IAccountService service) {
        super(service);
        this.service = service;
        System.out.println("AccountController-CONSTRUCTOR");
    }
}
```

The service class

```
@Service
public class AccountService extends AbsBaseDataService<Account> implements IAccountService {
[...]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I create a hierarchy interfaces in my solution and it works, but I don't know why works with interface and why not with class...I need study AOP.

Comment: I explained that (rather quickly) in my answer above. Do you need clarifications ? AOP lets you do things "around" your method call (i.e. before and after your call). In order to do that, your class needs to be proxied, so those calls can be executed

Comment: Ok :) Please accept the answer if you think it answers your problem. Thanks !